# Setting a Variable Once... I don't Know How to Explain (Android Projgramming)

Tags: android, variables

This is kind of hard to explain, so i'll try the best I can to inform you on my problem. I have a variable that changes every now and then. In the main app activity i have

```
int count = 0;
```

(count is the variable) I would like to only set that at the very beginning. The first time a viewer opens it up I want to set it to 0. After that, I want to save it every time the viewer leaves, and load it when the viewer opens the app back up.

Comment: We need more information. Is this supposed to count the times that the app has been launched? If so, you need to store it in the shared preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you write that before any of your function begins.

like

private int count=0;

public static void FunctionBegins()
{
...
}

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused. I don't why I didn't think of this